# Can you call a T-SQL stored procedure for individual charts in PowerBI when working in Direct Query mode?

Tags: sql, t-sql, powerbi, data-modeling, business-intelligence

Rather calling a stored procedure or running a T-SQL command in data source settings, I would like to run queries for each individual chart separately owing to the fact that data source remains the same. Maybe a dynamic query can do the job not sure?

Comment: So a DirectQuery connection for each chart?

Comment: I dont see a way to do that  maybe something like using dynamic parameters on runtime to change query, but then again there will other visuals that will be querying same datbase

Comment: Power BI isn't really designed to be used like this (although it *might* be possible in the future). DirectQuery is already essentially a dynamic query the pulls only the data that is needed for a visual. Is there some kind of transformations that you do with a stored procedure that you can't replicate with DAX?

Comment: Yes actually to avoid creating dynamic measures in direct mode sometimes dax can become complex which takes a heavy toll on report for a single visual. Specially if a schema at dB level is pre defined and there is little you could do to model except changing the tables to import and then modelling according to requirement.

Comment: I think Google data studio in this regard gives you capability to use query for individual visuals.